# how to set focusup and down for edit text

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i have no of edit text in the UI. i wish to set focus up and down when we press up and down arrow. i have used **"android:nextFocusDown"** but it is not working.

(e.g like we use tab to move the curser for the next)

is there any code to set it in xml, please let me know it.

Comment: you can achieve that with small piece of code from your activity.

Comment: what you mean saying focus up or down? you mean the keyboard or what?

Comment: @PratikSharma can u provide the code ....

Comment: @saran Posted small example for this you can apply same in your xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText2" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks, i am using the same code but it is not working as i mentioned it in the question .Is there any other way...

Comment: There is method called `setNextFocusDownId` to set focus from the code , so you can use that too.